# Add sprite after scale also get scaled

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have to Sprites A and B ( A is human body and B is head ). I want to add sprite B to sprite A and to move together and I done this by
`A->addChild(B)` and it works. Problem is when I want to scale only body and then add head to small body ( head should be normal size ) and I done this like

```
A->setScaleY(0.3);
A->addChild(B);
```

but I also get B to be scaled. How to scale only body and then add head of normal size to small body ?

Comment: since head is added on body that is body is parent for head then if you scale parent then child also scale.

Answer (score 1):

B is child of A so will be scaled with A this is correct... I recommend you to  make third Sprite C (skeleton) and add A(body), B(head) sprites to it. After that you can scale A, B independent and move them all with sprite C or scale whole human body with all your parts with C(skeleton) sprite.

Answer (score 1):

Two way to solution this.

1. Node/Sprite C

   ```
   Sprite A;
   Sprite B;
   Sprite C;

   A->setScaleY(0.3);

   C->addChild(A);
   C->addChild(B);
   ```
2. also set B scale.

   ```
   float scale = 0.3f;
   A->setScaleY(scale);
   B->setScaleY(1/scale);
   A->addChild(B);
   ```